Are Artificers subject to the same magic item restrictions as other characters in AL?
The current 2024 Adventurer's League rules stipulate that characters may bring permanent magic items they've gained from other adventurers of Uncommon rarity or higher per the following tier criteria:

Tier 1: 1 item
Tier 2: 3 items
Tier 3: 6 items
Tier 4: 10 items

Furthermore, for all tiers, characters may only carry 5 Common rarity magic items.
At 2nd level, the Artificer is able to learn Infusions and also have 2 infused items at once. Generally, none of these infused magic items have a stated rarity, so presumably an Artificer wouldn't need to count any of those infusions when counting their magic items.
However, one of the infusion options is Replicate Magic Item, which allows the Artificer to create various magic items all of which are at least Uncommon rarity or higher. Furthermore, Replicate Magic Item is an infusion which can be taken multiple times allowing multiple items to be made.
During Tier 1 play, is the Artificer allowed to use all of the magic items they create with the Replicate Magic Item infusion. For example, could they start play with a Bag of Holding and Sending Stones, both of which are Uncommon rarity?
My questions are as follows:

Does an Artificer include magic items they create using the Replicate Magic Item infusion for the purposes of limits on the tier list?
If yes, would those limits apply if they used different infusions? For example, taking the Enhanced Weapon infusion which effectively turns a weapon into a +1 weapon.


Yes, Artificers are subject to the same permanent magic item limits, but their infusions are not permanent magic items
Artificers are subject to the same limits as other characters in regards to permanent magic items, however, infusions should not be treated as permanent magic items, but rather as a class feature. Similar to how Paladins become immune to disease with Divine Health; Artificers are able to use their Infuse Item class feature to quickly create a +1 magic weapon or a bag of holding.
However, while these items might function similarly to their permanent magic item counterpart, they are notably different because the magic used to create an infused item is subject to ending in a variety of situations (gradually after the Artificer dies or the Artificer replacing their knowledge of the infusion with a different one). Additionally, none of the listed infusions include a rarity descriptor on them. Even items created using Replicate Magic Item lack such a descriptor because the feature's language simply states that the Artificers, "replicates a particular magic item," it doesn't use language that says they create a magic item.
With this in mind, Artificer players should keep track of their magic items created using their infusions separately from the permanent magic items they received. I would be inclined to say they ought to list the items created via infusions under their Class Abilities on their character sheets, however, they are still subject to attunement limitations, thus there may be some repeats on the character sheet.
The permanent magic items they receive during play will be subject to the Tier limits.
